Attempted edit with spam
I just received an approval request for this edit https://italian.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/641
Is there anything that can be done (besides rejecting the edit?)


What does "anonymous user" mean, any clue? Shouldn't someone have an account to post here?

not necessarily, you can post as a guest, then when you delete the cookies you will lose your credential and be able to continue... I don't know if this is the case, maybe it is a user already flagged and deleted?

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234932/if-i-see-a-spam-vandalism-suggested-edit-should-i-do-anything-extra-about-it

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194252/what-is-an-anonymous-user-capable-of

While rejecting this edit, you can mark it as 'vandalism':


Really? To me it looks like a bug. Maybe on some other Stack there is someone talking about corn and 'tamales' (no idea on what are those) and they modified something wrongly and it ended up here?

In teoria è pensabile, ma in questo caso, visto che si menziona per esteso e in maiuscolo una marca dicendo che è biuona, e che sia nel testo che nel commento alla modifica sono menzionati URL che finiscono con “shop.asp”, sono incline a non crederlo.

Per curiosità avevo cercato il testo, è stato copiato pari pari (eccetto i link) da un commento in un blog di ricette... non ho la minima idea del perchè l'abbiano messo li', magari lo spammer ha risposto alla parola chiave fonzie (gli snack) :D
Comunque se girate in meta.stackexchange ci sono un sacco di spam "nascosti" creativi, fatti molto meglio di questo!

Forgot to translate my comment: It is possible, in theory, but in this case, since a brand is mentioned by name and in capital letters in laudatory terms, and since both in the edit and in the comment to the edit URLs ending in “shop.asp” are given, I am prone not to consider it a bug.
